# Enabling Eslint on typescript files

Tags: typescript, webstorm, eslint

On webstorm eslint setting, there is an "extra eslint options" field.
In this, I added:

```
--ext .ts
```

from the eslint [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#ext) which is supposed to allow eslint to work on custom file extension, in this case .ts files.
This does nothing. Is my syntax wrong ? Anyway to enable Eslint on .ts files, maybe from the .eslintrc file ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`--ext` allows using custom javascript extensions, you can't force ESLint to work for languages other than JavaScript by passing a different file extension to it.

You can try using [typescript-eslint-parser](https://github.com/eslint/typescript-eslint-parser) to enable ESLint for Typescript - it allows building a syntax tree from typescript code that can be passed to ESLint for linting.

But I'd suggest using Typescript linters for inspecting TypeScript code. You can try [TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint), for example.

**Update**: since 2017.1.3, WebStorm supports ESLint + typescript-eslint-parser; you just need to install both `typescript` plugin and `typescript-eslint-parser` and modify your ESLint config accordingly:

```
"parser": "typescript-eslint-parser",
"plugins": ["typescript"]
```

Comment: What is the answer here? TSLint or typescript-eslint-parser? Tried TSLint which does not seem to work right off without doing some research.

Comment: the answer is - you can try both, but I'd suggest TSLint. If it doesn't 'work right' for you, it's not a reason for downvoting the answer. It's not an advertise, it's just the explanation why ESLint `--ext` does nothing for TypeScript

Comment: **typescript-eslint-parser**  doesn't work in any case for me.

Comment: when I use `"parser": "typescript-eslint-parser",`, my other projects with javascript can't be validated and formated by vscode eslint plugin,do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Anyone using typescript-eslint-parser should use @typescript-eslint/parser instead
https://eslint.org/blog/2019/01/future-typescript-eslint

Comment: Make sure that you have WebStorm 2019.1 or above to have integration with @typescript-eslint

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line into your .eslintrc.json

```
"plugins": ["typescript"]
```

In my case, I made eslint format my `.vue` and my `.ts` files by using this config :

```
{
  "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
  "parserOptions": {
     "parser": "typescript-eslint-parser"
   },
  "extends": [
     "eslint:recommended",
     "plugin:vue/recommended",
     "typescript"
  ],
  "plugins": ["typescript"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

2020 answer:

My problem was ESLint errors/warnings weren't showing up in the Problems tab in WebStorm (this also works for Rider) for .ts files, even though VS Code was working fine (showing warnings/errors) for the very same file.

Solution:

1. Press CTRL+SHIFT+A

---

2. Search for "Registry..."
   [image]

---

3. Start typing `eslint.additional.file.extensions` to find that registry entry
   [image]

---

4. Set value of `eslint.additional.file.extensions` to `js,ts` (like in screenshot above)

Probably you should restart editor just to be sure. This worked for me (errors/warnings started appearing in Problems section just like in VS Code) and I'm using `@typescript-eslint/[somethinghere]` rules etc.

Comment: Do you know which config file on the disk (on linux) is impacted by this change?

Comment: I don't believe this is saved in a file. I assume you're asking because you want to share this setting between colleagues - I had the same problem and couldn't find a solution. I just put the link to this answer in my documentation that tells people to enable eslint manually.