# Private/public modifiers with Typescript and eslint

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to configure eslint to allow Typescript class member modifiers (private, public)?

Currently if I write:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(private bar) {

    }
}
```

eslint tells me: `error  Parsing error: Unexpected token`

I'm using `"parser": "babel-eslint"` in my `.eslintrc`

Comment: Deleting my answer... as I did not know that syntax was possible. Anyway it seems horrible for readability

Comment: Typescript is not javascript, you cannot use java script related tools on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enabling Eslint on typescript files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910592/enabling-eslint-on-typescript-files)

Answer (score 3):

[***TSLint is deprecated***](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534)

Try `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` package instead.

Check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin) for more information about typescript eslint plugin.

Comment: yes, it resolves my quetion

Answer (score 0):

[babel-eslint doesn't support TypeScript](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/134). You might be better off using [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) instead.

Comment: tslint doesn't support an `indent-size` rule :|

Comment: @kamilkp: Yeah, it's not perfect ): But it's pretty much the only well-supported option when it comes to TypeScript linting.

Comment: @JoeClay tslint is deprecated